# Sending data from one php file to other php file

Tags: php

I want to send data from one php file to other php file to authenticate a user . None of them can be html files . And I cant send it as header as it appears in the url .  Plz give me some suggestions.

Comment: I think you need to expand your question a little. Are these files on the same server? What's in the files?

Comment: @Matt Files in the same server,same directory . One file contains authentication information(username,password etc ) and the other file will verify the information . And I can't embed the two files

Comment: Is the authentication information (usernames, passwords) stored as an array?

Comment: If the userz cant be html files, cant they use HTTP protocol, e.g. `$_POST` or `$_SESSION`? and redirectionz? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for this, to send a secure `POST` request, **even** if the receiver script is on another server. That will not expose anything in the URL, **however** Firebug may be able to see the request. To get around this, simply make sure that your `auth key` and the password that is being sent, are [hashed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php).

Something like this (untested)

Here is the sender script

```
<?php

///// Sender.php ///////

//Set up some vars
$url = 'http://domain.com/Receiver.php';

$user = 'someusername';
$pw = 'somepassword';
$auth_key = 'YourSecretAuthKey';

$fields = array(
            'auth'=>urlencode($auth_key),
            'user'=>urlencode($user),
            'pw'=>urlencode($pw)
        );

// Init. string
$fields_string = '';
// URL-ify stuff
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

And the receiver script:

```
<?php

////// Receiver.php //////

if(!isset($_POST['authkey']))die('Error: No Auth Key');
if(!isset($_POST['user']))die('Error: No Username!');
if(!isset($_POST['pw']))die('Error: No password!');

$auth_key = $_POST['auth'];
$correct_authkey = 'YourSecretKey';

if($auth_key!=$correct_authkey)die('WRONG AUTH KEY!!!!');

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];

//// Here you can process your username and password

?>
```

A `POST` request is pretty secure, but if you are handling crucial information, you could always hash the auth key and password. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt or hash the authentication data and send as part of the `POST` body or in the URL. On the receiving end, look at `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: $_GET goes against the OP's prefered solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the auth information into the other file thusly:

```
<?php
require_once('authentication_infomation.php');
doTheAuthentication($authentication_information);
?>
```

See:

http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

For more information.

Comment: `And I can't embed the two files` - OP's comment on his OP. :)

Comment: @Jeff I may have misunderstood that comment. I assumed OP was unable to embed the files due to being unaware of how to do it.